# How to get path of java files including /src/

Tags: java, eclipse

im Working on a project that can compile/run existing java files in PC.

most of code works pretty well, but im having a problem at getting the path of java files.

here are the problematic codes

```
void uploadJ() {    
    System.out.print("Insert File name : "); //ex)HelloWorld.java
    FileName = sc.next(); 
    }

void Compile(){ 
    String s = null;
    File file = new File(FileName);
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

    try {
        Process oProcess = new ProcessBuilder("javac", path).start();
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oProcess.getErrorStream()));
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(E_file, true);
                fw.write(s);
                fw.flush();
                fw.close();
        } 
    } catch...
}
```

For instance, when i put HelloWorld.java as a file name,

the absolute path of the HelloWorld.java should be ***C:\Users\user\eclipse-
workspace\TermProject\src\HelloWorld.java***,

but instead, the result is  ***C:\Users\user\eclipse-
workspace\TermProject\HelloWorld.java***.

it misses ***/src/*** so it always ends up with  ***javac: file not found error.***

Comment: When Eclipse compiles your code, `src ` doesn't exist. Class files are moved to `target` or `bin `

Comment: You cannot rely on current working directory being set to anything in Java.

Comment: Also, you might want to add a `-cp` argument if you want to compile an actual project rather than a file

Answer (score 0):

When your application has been compiled, there will be no `src` directory. This working directory could also be set to anything.
You also can't guarantee that the file you are looking for is an actual file, in the context of a jar file, it isn't.

However, you can load files from the classpath. You can make use of [`Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):

> Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class.`.

Finding the file can be accomplished by calling `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + FileName)`, with the `/` causing the search to occur from the resource root.

To use this with `javac`, you'll have to create a temporary file and populate it with the data stream you get from `getResourceAsStream`.